# Dimension only tracks one Customer

Tags: google-analytics

I'm stumped.  We only get one fruit type showing up in analytics when there should be multiple showing up for pageview tracking per fruit type;

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{analyticsAccount}}"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', '{{analyticsAccount}}', {
        'custom_map': {
            'dimension1': 'fruitType',
            'dimension2': 'userId',
        }
    });

    gtag('set', 'fruitType', {{fruitType}});
    gtag('set', 'userId', '{{userId}}');

</script>
<!-- end global site tag -->
```

For some reason, it's only showing one fruit type when looking at either custom or standard reports and we know our system is sending in many types of fruit.

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have a public page I can share.

Comment: what is the scope of your 'fruitType' dimension?

Comment: Can you share page to test how dimensions are sending?

Comment: well isn't the scope page views since It's that by default?

Comment: in the admin custom dimension, it's setup a a session level param

Comment: Do you have many types of fruits on one page?

Comment: how are you passing the value to fruitType?

Comment: we pass the fruitType value from our DB.  We want to track fruitType per company..just pretend company is a fruit type, we want to track page views for each fruitType and so we assign fruitType as a dimension for page views but depending on what our API returns for fruitType it depends on which company is logged into our site

Comment: > Do you have many types of fruits on one page?
no it's based on logged in user, basically fruit type relates to a company but we set fruitType for that company from our DB

Comment: Do I need the set commands?  I'm sure set commands are what tie my custom DB data to those dimensions but there are barely any docs that talk about it in depth enough

Comment: or if I do need those set commands, is it not working (showing different fruit types) because those set commands need to come before the configuration line?

Comment: I don't understand why most the docs don't even mention using the set command much